# KeyError: 'labels [data] not contained in axis'

Tags: python, pandas, append, typeerror, delete-row

I have tried several different methods to add a row to an existing Pandas Dataframe.  For example I tried the solution [here](https://www.quantopian.com/posts/how-to-add-entries-to-a-dataframe).  However I was not able to correct the issue.  I have reverted back to my original code in hopes someone can help me here.

Here is my code:

```
print('XDF Created, Starting Bucket Separation...')
XDFDFdrop = pd.DataFrame.duplicated(XDFDF,subset='LastSurveyMachineID')
index_of_unique = XDFDF.drop_duplicates(subset='LastSurveyMachineID')
for index,row in zip(XDFDFdrop,XDFDF.itertuples()):
    if index:
        goodBucket.append(row)
    else:
        badBucket.append(row)
goodBucketDF = pd.DataFrame(goodBucket)
badBucketDF = pd.DataFrame(badBucket)

print('Bucket Separation Complete, EmailPrefix to F+L Test Starting...')
for emp , fname , lname , row1 in zip(goodBucketDF['EmailPrefix'] , goodBucketDF['Fname'] , goodBucketDF['Lname'] , goodBucketDF.itertuples()):
    for emp2 , row2 in zip(goodBucketDF['EmailPrefix'] , goodBucketDF.itertuples()):
        if columns != rows:
            temp = fuzz.token_sort_ratio((fname+lname),emp)
            temp2 = fuzz.token_sort_ratio((fname+lname),emp2)
            if abs(temp - temp2) < 10:
                badBucketDF.append(list(row2))
                goodBucketDF = goodBucketDF.drop(row2)
                removed = True
        rows += 1
    if removed:
        badBucketDF.append(list(row2))
        goodBucketDF = goodBucketDF.drop(row2)
        removed = False
    columns += 1
```

Please note: XDFDF is a relatively large data set that is built using pandas and was pulled from a database (it should not affect the code you see just figured I would disclose that information).

This is my Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/john/PycharmProjects/Greatness/venv/Recipes.py", line 122, in <module>
    goodBucketDF = goodBucketDF.drop([rows])
  File "/Users/john/PycharmProjects/Greatness/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 3694, in drop
    errors=errors)
  File "/Users/john/PycharmProjects/Greatness/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3108, in drop
    obj = obj._drop_axis(labels, axis, level=level, errors=errors)
  File "/Users/john/PycharmProjects/Greatness/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3140, in _drop_axis
    new_axis = axis.drop(labels, errors=errors)
  File "/Users/john/PycharmProjects/Greatness/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 4387, in drop
    'labels %s not contained in axis' % labels[mask])
KeyError: 'labels [(15, '1397659289', 'joshi.penguin@gmail.com', 'jim', 'smith', '1994-05-04', 'joshi.penguin', 'CF032611-8A86-4688-9715-E1278E75D046')] not contained in axis'
```

Process finished with exit code 1

I would like to know if anyone has a solution to this error so that: I can add a take a row from one Dataframe, place it in the the other DataFrame (does not need to be in order, and I don't care if index duplicates or not).  Once it is in its new Dataframe I want to remove it from the old one.

My current issue is removing the row from the old Dataframe.  Any help would be appreciated.

If you have any questions on the code please let me know and I will respond as soon as I can.  Thank you for your help.

**Edit 1**

Below I have included a printout of row1.  Hopefully this will help as well.

```
Pandas(Index=1, _1=2, entity_id='1180722688', email='assassin_penguin@live.com', Fname='jim', Lname='smith', Birthdate='1990-09-14', EmailPrefix='assassin_penguin', LastSurveyMachineID=None)
```

Comment: Kind of hard to tell from your code but what if you just give it what it wants, i.e. a list: `badBucket.append(list(row))`?

Comment: I attempted this.  It seems to be working for the badbucket line, however now I'm getting an error for deleting the item out of the old list.  I get: KeyError: Pandas(Index=1, _1=2, entity_id='1180722688', email='assassin_altair21@live.com', Fname='Adam', Lname='Buskirk', Birthdate='1990-09-14', EmailPrefix='assassin_altair21', LastSurveyMachineID=None) when using row1 or TypeError: '[1, 2, '1180722688', 'assassin_altair21@live.com', 'Adam', 'Buskirk', '1990-09-14', 'assassin_altair21', None]' is an invalid key, when using list(row1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that XDFDF is a `pandas.DataFrame`, shouldn't the following work?

```
XDFDFdrop = pd.DataFrame.duplicated(XDFDF,subset='LastSurveyMachineID')
goodBucket = XDFDF.loc[~XDFDFdrop] #the ~ negates a boolean array
badBucket = XDFDF.loc[XDFDFdrop]
```

Edit:

The updated error comes from you passing an entire row rather than an index to the function `pandas.DataFrame.drop`.

Comment: Yes that does work for the first section of code.  And @tobesecret comment works for the append part.  Currently getting an issue when trying to delete the row from the old Dataframe.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer then? It seems like I answered your initial question which was how to add rows in the place that you were getting an error.
I was able to fix that because it was pretty obvious but without a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I will have no chance to solve the second section of your code.